# Java: Get current Date and Time from Server not System clock

Tags: java, datetime

In my Java program, I need to create an instance of the current moment in time. I use

```
Date date = new Date();
```

This gives me the current date and time as per the host machine's system clock. Is there any way I can get the current date and time from an online server? The world time server perhaps?

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510649/how-to-make-my-java-app-get-global-time-from-some-online-clock) and it describes what I want but I'm afraid I need more help than what's provided there.

In a nutshell, I want to get a date and time that is not dependant on the host machine's system clock.

Thanks!

Comment: Similar: [*how to make my java app get global time from some online clock*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2510649/642706)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Local network

If your machine is connected to a local network, connect to some machine acting as a trustworthy [time server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_server). You could write your own such time server.

### *Network Time Protocol*

Or you could use the well-worn [*Network Time Protocol (NTP)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) with existing server and client implementations bundled with most any [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system). For more on this, see [the accepted Answer by aioobe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2817511/642706).

Consider placing that time server computer in [network’s DMZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29) so as to updates from time servers on the Internet such as the [pool.ntp.org project](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi) or [those provided by the United States federal government (NIST)](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi).

## Internet

If your machine is connected to the internets, connect to a trustworthy time server. As discussed above, use a custom protocol such as a web service, or use [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).

This is discussed in the Question, [*how to make my java app get global time from some online clock*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2510649/642706).

See also Questions: [*Java NTP client*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/925191/642706), and [*Java client for time server, such as Network Time Protocol (NTP)*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48920/1255).

## Radio Clock

Obtain a [radio clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_clock) with a [USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) connection for output of current time  synchronized by a time code transmitted by a radio transmitter connected to a time standard such as an atomic clock. Transmitters are broadcasting in many countries all over the world.

The [Meinberg Global](https://www.meinbergglobal.com/) company, at least, offers [several such devices](https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/products/usb-clocks.htm).

[image: photo of a couple of external radio clock devices]

## GPS

Similar to the radio clocks above, a receiver of GPS ([Global Positioning System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System)) signals might also capture and relay the [time signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_signal). Or perhaps [GALILEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_(satellite_navigation)), [GLONASS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLONASS) or other [Radionavigation-satellite service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radionavigation-satellite_service).

[image]

## Sundial

Position a [sundial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sundial) outside a window. Attach a [webcam](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webcam) to the computer in question. Position the webcam in the window. Write an app to interpret the time of day from current image of the sundial.

[image: photo of a sundial on a pedestal in a garden]

**Caveat:** This solution does not function in [Seattle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seattle).

---

## `java.time.Clock`

To harness any of these suppliers of the current moment, write a subclass of the abstract [`java.time.Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) class.

You can pass your `Clock` implementation as an argument to the various *java.time* methods. For example, [`Instant.now( clock )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now-java.time.Clock-).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now( yourClockGoesHere ) ;
```

For testing purposes, note the alternate implementations of `Clock` available statically from `Clock` itself: [`fixed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#fixed-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-), `offset`, `tick`, and more.

Avoid the legacy date-time classes from the earliest versions of Java, such as `Date` & `Calendar`. These troublesome classes are entirely supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Upvoted for the sundial, which is obviously the correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

You could have a look at the Java NTP Client demo available at

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/examples/ntp/NTPClient.java.html

and some example code that utilizes this client

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/examples/ntp/TimeClient.java.html

It's about 170 lines of well documented java code.

Answer (score -4):

Normally servers sync their time regulary with online time servers. So your server time should be accurate. If not, contact your admin.

To get e.g. the GMT time, use the Calendar and TimeZone classes.

Comment: I'm not running my Java application on a server. It is a desktop app.

Comment: Well, your desktop does so too. Atleast, the default windows installation does (and afaik linux systems too)

Comment: Yes, The desktop syncs time , but it is subjected to tampering which makes it unreliable at times.