# How to avoid system date dependency?

Tags: visual-c++, date

I want to break the dependency on the system clock in my application as it can be tampered with. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817475/java-get-current-date-and-time-from-server-not-system-clock) for JAVA. Can anyone point me to something like this or something that helps me achieve this for c++?

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that is just a web call? Someone can tamper with it by doing a man in the middle attack on the web call.

(yes it is harder than just changing the date, but unless you are talking to a secure host it could be intercepted).

I assume you are doing this for some kind of "expire demo code after it has ran for 30 days?"  If so, there may be better ways to do that...

Comment: You are right my requirements are along those lines could please point me towards "better ways".

Comment: Can you please give me ideas as what these other methods are?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like an [NTP Class](http://blog.p-jansson.com/2010/03/ntp-client-using-boostasio.html) (this one looks to use boost)? I have not used this one, so ymmv.