# programmatically how to get actual time in android if i changed the device time

Tags: android

can Anybody please give me exact solution of this problem programmaticaly i.e. when i change the device time it's taking device time but i want that it should take actual time from internet.
i am using this code...

```
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        String date = dateFormat.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

i tried this also

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    int myfrmt =(c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+ c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    String satyam=Integer.toString(myfrmt);`
```

but in both the case i got device time .... not real time

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(activity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
long time = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getTime();
```

This will provide the time through your network provider.

Comment: gives device time

Comment: yeah it gives device time

Comment: Actually it doesn't if you have location service turned on. It will take some time, but it will give you the actual time without an internet.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064750/how-to-get-current-time-from-internet-in-android). The thread has multiple answers which are worth checking out. I would recommend the "correct" answer although you have to include a library for this. If you use the first answer please also notice the comments concerning server choice.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a simple AJAX call to

http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now

A handy web service which returns current GMT time that you could manipulate.