# How to get the current date that is not generated from mobile date?

Tags: android

I want to get the current date that is not dependant on the mobile time. If user change the date in mobile then also it will return the present date. How can I get the current date that is not generated by the mobile?

Comment: refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064750/how-to-get-current-time-from-internet-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
  try {
                TimeTCPClient updateTime = new TimeTCPClient();
                try {
                    updateTime.setDefaultTimeout(60000);
                    updateTime.connect("your time server name...");
                    Log.d("TimeLog", client.getDate() + "");
                } finally {
                    updateTime.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```