# Get the current Date from Google or By LocationManager [GMT +6]

Tags: java, android

I have created a app which get the time from Mobile. I want to get the Date from google or by LocationManager . so how can i get it?

Answer (score 0):

well you can use `new Date();` and this will return simply current date and time, also you can format date using `SimpleDateFormat` of `java.util` package

for example:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd, yyyy");
        try {
            String date=  simpleDateFormat.format(new Date().getTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

so this will give output like MON, NOV 27, 2017

Comment: i want that if my mobile date is wrong app will get the curremt date.

Comment: @Dom then you need to use sim clock time or any internet based time clock api

Comment: @Dom refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064750/how-to-get-current-time-from-internet-in-android