# How to get exact time on android studio?

Tags: java, android

I do understand that it is possible to get the time set by the user by using `new Date()`. But i face problems when the user set the time wrongly in his phone. How can i access the exact time regardless of what the user set?

Comment: call external ntp server

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064750/how-to-get-current-time-from-internet-in-android

Comment: I think you should first define what are you going to take as the source for the best time.