# How to get current date in android? (not the date set in device's local memory)

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android app which is time dependent. However, I faced an issue where user can change the functionality of the app by just overriding the time in their local machine which in turn provides the overridden time to the app. So, how one get the current time irrespective of what is set in local memory of a device?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064750/how-to-get-current-time-from-internet-in-android

Comment: https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android

Comment: clock skewing can also be detected by occasionally remembering the current time.

Answer (score 0):

Time in miliseconds

```
long millis = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

Time in hours

```
int hours = new Time(System.currentTimeMillis()).getHours();
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question...

Comment: Initially I think it is the answer you wanted. but now i am guessing you are requiring the current time from internet.. you can use  TimeTCPClient client for internet time