# How to get current time in Android if the calendar time has been changed manually?

Tags: android

How do I get the real internet time in the case the user changes date and time manually in Android ?

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far

Comment: You should probably get it from some server.
Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064750/how-to-get-current-time-from-internet-in-android) will help you.