# Get date and time from internet or google (Android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm developing an app where user will register products and i need the date and time when he registered a product in UTC+5 from google or internet. I really don't have any ideas about it. Format - Mon. 03.12.2016 23:54. Also will there be a way to change the language so that saturday would be written in Russian?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current time from internet in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064750/how-to-get-current-time-from-internet-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

There is [a library called TrueTime](https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android) for getting true device time. Wiki sample (using Rx):

```
TrueTimeRx.build()
        .initializeRx("time.google.com")
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(date -> {
            Log.v(TAG, "TrueTime was initialized and we have a time: " + date);
        }, throwable -> {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        });
```

Comment: I just need a time in UTC+5, and put that in String variable.

Comment: @S4RD0R Please search for how to do that, it’s already described in many places.

Answer (score 1):

Using the HttpGet, Client and Response, I manage to get a server's current time from the response Date Header. I can call this all the times I want and will get confident responses (Google is almost 100% available and I can trust on getting correct Date and Time)

```
try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("https://google.com/"));
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            String dateStr = response.getFirstHeader("Date").getValue();
            //Here I do something with the Date String
            System.out.println(dateStr);

        } else{
            //Closes the connection.
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.d("Response", e.getMessage());
    }catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Response", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Check this Project : [Click Here](https://github.com/muntasiraonik/Get-Time-From-Google)

Comment: Hello bro, HttpClient is not support anymore in SDK 23 and UP, do you have the updated version of this?

Comment: @ClintonCanarias Check this - https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android

Answer (score -1):

Use Below Code

```
static final String DATEFORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

public static Date GetUTCdatetimeAsDate()
{
    //note: doesn't check for null
    return StringDateToDate(GetUTCdatetimeAsString());
}

public static String GetUTCdatetimeAsString()
{
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATEFORMAT);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    final String utcTime = sdf.format(new Date());

    return utcTime;
}

public static Date StringDateToDate(String StrDate)
{
    Date dateToReturn = null;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATEFORMAT);

    try
    {
        dateToReturn = (Date)dateFormat.parse(StrDate);
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return dateToReturn;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
String datetime = dateformat.format(c.getTime());
System.out.println(datetime);
```

Comment: This can be used only for getting the date and time from device, right? I wrote that i need from INTERNET? Are you ok?