# How do I get network time in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have problem to get the Network Time in Flutter Web. I used **NTP package**, but NTP is not supported in the **WEB Platform** of the flutter. Please, is there someone to help me out this problem ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70806264/13406356

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get network DateTime.Now()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64026825/how-to-get-network-datetime-now)

Comment: @Lucie! No dear, this is not ...