# How to get perfect UTC Time in java/android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, datetime

I am trying to get UTC time in my application but unfortunately every time I am getting my current emulator Date and Time Instead of UTC.

Tried,

1. `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`
2. `ZonedDateTime utcTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);`
3. `DateTime now = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC);`

**My code:**

```
//create UTC time
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    System.out.println("DATETIME ==> " + cal.getTime());
    ZonedDateTime utcTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println("DATETIME = " + utcTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
    DateTime now = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC);
    System.out.println("DATETIME = " + now);
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: When I set my emulator time to network provided time then it is working fine..
So, why this is happening can you explain that please??

Comment: UTC is depend on device time ?

Comment: okay, I got it .. thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current time from internet in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064750/how-to-get-current-time-from-internet-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
private String getCurrentDateTimeAccordingToUTC(String format) {
    Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    return simpleDateFormat.format(date);
}


String date = getCurrentDateTimeAccordingToUTC("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
Log.e("date--","inUTC--:"+date);
```

Comment: Got this UTC time:==>  2021-07-26T15:05
but Actually UTC date is ==> 27 and I am getting 26 which is my emulator date.

Comment: Conversion of date time is dependent on current date time of device.

Comment: But I don't want to conversion I want Actual UTC time.

Comment: Check this project - https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android, for getting actual UTC date time without dependent on device time

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. (Yes, you can use it on Android.)