# How to get time and date not from the phone

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In android studio kotlin or firebase how do I get the utc time and date that will be same on everyone's phone.

This is the code for getting utc time:

```
fun getUtcTimeAndDate(): String {
    val df = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, h:mm a")

    df.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
    return df.format(Date())
}
```

It gets the utc time from your phone but some phones have slightly different utc times.

I want to get the utc time from somewhere that on everyone's phone will be the same.

Comment: you need to get it from backend server.

Comment: Can I get it from firebase?

Comment: @Leo yes you can by using Cloud Functions

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/ServerTimestamp

Comment: Did you search? I readily found this one: [How to get current time from internet in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064750/how-to-get-current-time-from-internet-in-android). There are a number of similar questions with answers.

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.