# Android Kotlin / JAVA - get current world time / UTC in seconds since 1970

Tags: java, android, kotlin, timestamp, utc

As the title says I need the current workd time in seconds since 1970.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

and

```
val df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance()
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("gmt"))
val gmtTime = df.format(Date())
```

But both are showing the time which is based on the phone time, so when a user changes the phone time manually it will be affected

Is there a way to get the current workd time in seconds without using an extern API?

Comment: "without using an extern API" you're going to need to talk to *something*.

Comment: But what is android using to set the current time automatically? So far I used an extern API but there was trouble since the latest patch which I fixed. But I don't want to worry with every damn android update so I want to use as few APIs as possible in general

Comment: @KingDingeling That would be a [Network Time Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) server, which would be an external resource. Otherwise a phone is reliant on its internal clock, which as you mentioned can be changed.

Comment: See [How to get current time from internet in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064750/how-to-get-current-time-from-internet-in-android). Search for more similar questions and answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the only way to get time NOT based on device clock is to request it from some Web API service.

Comment: Ok, we all wish we could get real time without relating on device clock :D

Comment: NTP is a nice well-known protocol for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817475/java-get-current-date-and-time-from-server-not-system-clock

Comment: as @Michael Dodd said NTP use external API