# Getting an exact unix time stamp that the user cant change on Android/kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, timestamp

The api im calling requires that i send a unix timestamp in seconds in order to get the changes that occurred to an entity since that time.
i can't use `currentTimeMillis` because that can be changed by user, and i cant use `elapsedRealtime()` is device dependent
is there away to get this time? 
source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock

Comment: Use an SNTP library to call a time server.

Comment: you can look at this answer, please :https://stackoverflow.com/a/54405264/10797722

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a repository that fetches the Unix time from a server, like this one

http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now

The only concern is that you need internet permission.