# How to get current time (NOT DEVICE)

Tags: java, android

How to get today's date and time NOT DEVICE i.e actual

I have tried this and many but all they give device time

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
```

Comment: maybe something like this ? http://worldtimeapi.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get time details from internet and then use it. Just Internet is required.

Use [android.net.sntp.SntpClient](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/net/SntpClient.java/) class.

```
SntpClient client = new SntpClient();
int timeout = 50000;
if (client.requestTime("time-a.nist.gov", timeout)) {
    long time = client.getNtpTime();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
    calendar.getTime();  // this should be your date
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Your code will not compile due to applying a Format with hours and minutes to a `Date`
2) You are using default Locale of the device so it will return the local date time.
3) You need to use a timezoned time and apply the timezone of Greenwitch to get current DateTime without any timezone applied.
Check [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) for more informations

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you might want to get the timestamp from a NTP (Network Time Protocol) server. And java has already had libraries to support your need.
Check this out. [(StackOverFlow) How to make my java app get global time from some online clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510649/how-to-make-my-java-app-get-global-time-from-some-online-clock)

Answer (score 0):

// get current default time 
    System.out.println( Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

```
// get different time zone
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
LocalTime localTime=LocalTime.now(zoneId);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
String formattedTime=localTime.format(formatter);
System.out.println("Current time of the day in Los Angeles: " + formattedTime);
```